# C# Objects in a list are overwriting each other

Tags: c#

The code I am looking at is as follows

```
string data;
string[] tokens;

while (sr.EndOfStream != true)
{
    data = sr.ReadLine();
    char delim = ',';
    tokens = data.Split(delim);
    Team t = new Team(tokens[0], int.Parse(tokens[1]), int.Parse(tokens[2]));
    TeamList.Add(t);
}

//Test to make sure the teams were stored properly
foreach(Team t in TeamList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
}

sr.Close();
```

When I use the foreach loop to write the team names out it displays 9 copies of Team9 (The teams are listed 1-9 in the text file line by line, with two numbers separated by commas to hold the wins and losses for each team, which is the reason there are delims with commas). This goes for any number of teams I add, if i add a 10th team it does 10 copies of team10, and if I use 8 teams it shows 8 copies of Team8. I added the foreach loop into the while loop to have it show the teams at each stage and it keeps overwriting all previous objects when it creates a new one, so for example the first time it runs the loop it shows Team1, then the next time it runs the loop it shows two lines of Team2, and so on. From my research I saw that this is usually caused by not declaring a new object inside of the loop, but in this case a new object is declared inside the loop.

Edit:  the Team class is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

 namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
 class Team
{
    private static string tn;
    private static int Wins, Losses;

    public Team()
    {

    }
    public Team(string name, int wins, int losses)
    {
        tn = name;
        Wins = wins;
        Losses = losses;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return tn + ", wins: " + Wins + ", losses: " + Losses;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return tn; }
    }
 }
}
```

The TeamList variable and main class are as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
 class Program
 {


    private static Random pick = new Random();

    private static List<Team> TeamList = new List<Team>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {      
        //Reading file io 
        Schedule(TeamList);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

static void Schedule(List<Team> TeamList)
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/Users/andre/Desktop/VisualStudioProjects/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/TeamList.txt");
        string data;
        string[] tokens;

        while (sr.EndOfStream != true)
        {
            data = sr.ReadLine();
            char delim = ',';
            tokens = data.Split(delim);
            Team t = new Team(tokens[0], int.Parse(tokens[1]), int.Parse(tokens[2]));
            TeamList.Add(t);
            foreach(Team x in TeamList)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
            }
        }


        //Test to make sure the teams were stored properly
        foreach(Team t in TeamList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
        }

        sr.Close();
      }
```

The text file is simply a file that contains the following

```
Team1,0,0
Team2,0,0
Team3,0,0
Team4,0,0
Team5,0,0
Team6,0,0
Team7,0,0
Team8,0,0
Team9,0,0
```

Comment: How is Team defined? What is TeamList?

Comment: Since `t` is a local variable, which is being created every time, there should be no problem. Show your `Team` implementation and `TeamList` declaration.

Comment: TeamList is a global variable declared as private static List<Team> TeamList = new List<Team>();. The Team class is defined as public Team(string name, int wins, int losses). I believe that should be the answers to your questions. Please tell me if you need anything else, I'm still fairly new to programming.

Comment: @Prolixitas Please show us your file and include your class definitions in your post - you'll get a better and faster answer if people are able to copy & paste your post and immediately replicate the issue.

Comment: I updated my post to include the portion of the main class I am having issues with and the Team class.

Comment: Remove `static` from your member variables in `Team`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
class Team
{
    private static string tn; //STATIC??
    private static int Wins, Losses; //STATIC??
}
```

`static` means the variable is shared between all instances of `Team` in your application. Remove it please. That is the problem.

Comment: I copied the class from some group members for a project and didn't even notice the variables were declared as static, thanks for the help.

Comment: @brainlesscoder I edited the post a bit to make it not-so-abrasive, as I don't think that kind of attitude is constructive on SO. Feel free to rollback if you wish, though.

Comment: @Prolixitas taking effort to provide [MCVE] could have helped you to find problem... (in current state of the question it look like you copied some code and did not even look at it - may be considered as negative sign by some)

Comment: @Rob, thanks and appreciate it.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Thanks I'll keep that in mind for the future.